# Rails 4 Spree Invoke callback "Undefined method for User xxxxx"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, spree

I want to use callbacks to modify the admin product controller to create a listing for each user. Using decorator in spree product model I added the "belongs_to :user" relation. In my custom user model I added the "has_many :products" relation and also added product_id and index product_id to my user data table. 
I have this:

```
Spree::Admin::ProductsController.class_eval do
create.before :user_products

private

 def user_products
    @user.objects.build params[object_name]
 end
end
```

object_name is a function inherited from ResourceController. It returns a string containing current object name “product”.

But it is not working. I am getting "undefined method objects for User XXXXX"
Looks like my association is not working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is name of your custom model and relationship with user and product?

Comment: My custom model is called User. 
In user model I have: 
has_many products, class_name: 'Spree::Product'
In Spree product model I have:
    if Spree.user_class
       belongs_to :user, class_name: Spree.user_class.to_s
    else
       belongs_to :user

Comment: Yes your association is wrong user_id should be there in spree_products table instead of product_id in user's table

Comment: Why? I am not creating many to many relationship. I have product_id in user table. So do you think I should remove product_id from user and add user_id in spree_product table?

Comment: yes it is has_many relation with products, many to many you need join table or has_thorugh association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key is wrong it should be like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Products table should have user_id

here is reference `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association`

[image]

Comment: Welcome @aminhs